# Rails 3 - Add months to a date string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I'm trying to add a number of months to a date.

I've tried numerous ways of converting the date string and adding the months but I'm getting nowhere, very fast.

I have `start_date` which is a date string "YYYY-MM-DD"
And I have `item.product.sub_period` which is the number of months I'd like to add.

I've tried many ways but am unsure as the correct way to convert the string into a format that can be modified.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Date.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") + item.product.sub_period.months
```

Just make sure `item.product.sub_period` returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Neal, I believe you can do this:

```
require 'date'
x = 3
a = Date.new(2012,2,3)
b = a >> x
```

as long as your date is a Date.